# How do I make this quick sort algorithm work with arrays that have duplicate elements?

Tags: java

Here is my code. It works fine, unless an array has duplicate elements. The quickSortRec method will keep halving arrays divided by a pivot. My paritition method will but a pivot-element in its sorted position. I believe my problem is in the partition method. But if I have >= or <= to my while statements, I get errors. What should I do?

```
public static void quickSortRec(int[] arr, int start, int end){
    if (start<end){ // Recursive case: There is a sizable array to working ie the array has more than one element
        int idx = partition(arr,start,end); // it returns the index of pivot which should be in its sorted position
        System.out.println(arr[idx] );
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        quickSortRec(arr,start,idx-1); // quick sorts that half right of the pivot
        quickSortRec(arr,idx+1,end); // quick sorts that half left of the pivot
    }
}

public static int partition(int[] arr, int start, int end){ 
    int pivot = arr[end]; // I choose the pivot to be the starting element
    int i = end;
    while (start < end){ // we will try to make everything smaller than the pivot left of it, and bigger right of it
        while (arr[start] < pivot ){ // if an element left  of the pivot is already smaller than it
            start++; // we just move on
        }
        while(arr[end] > pivot){ // if an element right of the pivot is already bigger than it
            end--; // we move on
        }
        if (start < end){ // we come here only when there is an element on the wrong side of the pivot
            int temp = arr[start];  // swap the pivot and that element on the wrong side
            arr[start] = arr[end];
            arr[end] = temp;
            //start++;
            //end++;
            //end--; // we move on and we don't move the start because that is the pivot index
        }

    }
    arr[end] = pivot;
    return end; // return pivot index which should be sorted
}
```

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest TL;DR: it's not urgent to us; learn to manage your time better.

Comment: Also, I don't think it works anyway, even for cases without dupes. `end--` never executes.

Comment: @Andy Turner, my algorithm does work without dupes. If you don't believe me, then u can test it out for yourself

Answer (score -1):

You almost had it right with changing them to >= and <=.
The only problem with setting both to be 'equal or' is that it won't clearly know if to put them above or below the pivot.
So the answer simply is only change one of them, so that the duplicates get sorted all onto one side.
For example like this:

```
    while (arr[start] <= pivot ){ // if an element left  of the pivot is already smaller than it
        start++; // we just move on
    }
    while(arr[end] > pivot){ // if an element right of the pivot is already bigger than it
        end--; // we move on
    }
```